# Adding software setup to installer

Tags: wix, installation

I'm writing an installer for an application.  Most of the installer is done and working, but I have on more step outstanding.  I need some way to add a setup window to the installer, that will take user input like server address and port, etc. and write these to the relevant files for system start-up.  This preferably done through a GUI of sorts inside the installer.
I've tried creating an executable file that runs after installation, but this does not always execute on different systems.

Is there a way to add a GUI to the installer itself that executes after the directory structures and files have been put into place?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't get your point. What is your requirement? Do you want call another installer from your installer.

Comment: The requirement is that the installation should happen with the default files and directory structures.

After these are in place a set of user inputs need to be configured for the system; for instance DB username and password, ports, server names, etc.

This does not necessarily mean another installer, but rather setting up the system during installation.  

Does that clarify the question?

Comment: Write DTF Custom action and execute that after InstallFiles
Sequence as deferred custom action.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should seriously consider doing this as a standalone app that runs when the app first runs and needs configuring. Then it's a program that runs in a user context and can be tested and debugged in the normal way. At least consider what the user is going to do if they want to change the server address or the port - will they need to uninstall your app and reinstall it just to change the server details or the port?

The GUI may not run correctly when started from the install for a number of reasons. It may be initiated with the system account if it's a deferred CA. It wasn't started from the interactive user shell, so it probably won't have any idea of a working directory. It's being run from an msiexec.exe process running in the system directory and maybe with a system account - that's not really the place to be doing your GUI configuration.

Comment: This is the best approach in my opinion as well, though I tend to suggest adding the whole setup to the main application executable. Using a separate EXE may be just as good - then it is an easier EXE file to update and can be maintained by a setup developer and not the development team.

Comment: Part of the requirement is to do the port & server setup during installation.  Let's say you want to install the server and need to setup server accounts and ports?  Would the best be to write a separate setup that runs after install?
I have tried this approach; it works on some installations, but doesn't work on Windows Server for instance - it runs the installation, but doesn't open the .exe after install.

Comment: Just to add to this.  Say your sever installation has different directories - deployments, database, etc.  If you run a separate setup, how do you resolve these directories?  
I know these can be done by things like environment variable, but I would like to steer clear of using these.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using WiX, it doesn't say so in your question but it's tagged with WiX.

I would have a read of http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited (or http://www.dizzymonkeydesign.com/blog/misc/adding-and-customizing-dlgs-in-wix-3/ has a relatively easy to read example), you can add or edit any of the dialogue boxes in the installer, you'll need to download the source to get at the built in dialog, and it does require some "play" to get everything quite right but worth it to get a professional looking installer.

Comment: I have done customisations on GUI's, but I thing @Vinoth's idea of using a DTF Custom action might be the way to go.
Thanks for the suggestion, anyway.